# How to show a post in the homepage of a Wordpress in specefic hours?

Tags: wordpress

How to show a post in the homepage of a Wordpress in specefic hours?

For example, how to show a post if the time of the Wordpress instalation is between 8-10pm.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you want a timer option on each post to control if it's visible on the front-/homepage? Is it for the main query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of WP [`current_time()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time) and PHP [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). And add a function to the theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function is_time_to_show_post()
{
    $now = current_time( 'timestamp' );
    $hour_now = date( 'H', $now ); // 24h format
    if( $hour_now >=20 && $hour_now <= 22 )
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

And in your template (`index.php`, `search.php`, etc):

```
<?php
if( is_time_to_show_post() ) {
    echo 'Your post';
}
?>
```

Make sure to set the correct GMT in `http://exmaple.com/wp-admin/options-general.php`.